Dark mode gets automatically disabled on re-login
I have observed this for the past two days.
When I login at the start of the day, I see that Stack Overflow is no longer in dark mode. I have to go to settings and set it back to dark mode.
For some reason, my preference is not persisted across sessions. It used to work fine, but no longer.
I use Google Chrome and version is:

Version 128.0.6613.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)


I can reproduce this.  Open incognito window, log into (sock) account, go to settings, turn on dark mode, close incognito window, open new incognito window, log into sock account, observe that it's in light mode.  Some of these steps may be unnecessary; I made no attempt to minimize the reproduction steps.

Yeah, it looks like the dark/light mode is not stored or read properly from the user settings on the DB, but stored on the session. I have dark-mode enabled, but when logging in with a different browser profile, I get light-mode.

I can repro this. A lot. The computer system I use logs me out several times a day (some dumb security thing). I've learned to live with it, but now it's annoying to have one more thing to reset every time I re-login.

Happened to me too (tried on multiple machines and browsers).

I have the same behavior on Edge on Win 10 and also on my mobile Android device (with chrome and Edge). I don't need to re-login or logout. It happend when I just stay on the same page for a while and then I refresh via F5. Also when I open links from google or bing search, my StackOverflow is always in light mode. Neither "Follow System" or "Dark" does work (only shortly after change in the value in the settings of my profile)

Likely related: Dark mode turned off after certain reputation events

Also being logged on some site (SO) and after a fresh login elsewhere (meta) the setting is being reset for all sites even these where user still maintains active session.

Why does Theme default to Light instead of System in the first place?

Apologies - sneaky regression. Fix will be out shortly
Update
OK should be sorted, if everyone could have a quick check?

I just logged in & had to manually change back to dark. If the fix is supposed to restore the correct value from before the bug, it doesn't. (And that's a poor fix.)

Yeah no that's somewhat regrettable but the bug itself was actively changing the value during login, meaning the old value was lost to the ether; we're now into 'if you really don't want to set it back yourself, let me know what you had it set as and I'll change it for you' territory. I was more asking whether the value you set persisted after subsequent logins

@cart since this is completed, in case this was also the cause for this issue you might want to mark that as completed as well.
