Dark mode turned off after certain reputation events
When I hit the new milestone at 500 reputation (got 501 reputation, to be exact), and gained access to the review queues, dark mode turned off when I clicked the notification and was redirected to the review queues.
I did not re-login.  But I had high-contrast mode enabled.

Another case related to the association bonus, with reproduction steps, is described in the comments.

Possibly related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431623 ?

Not sure what cause dark-mode to get turned off but in my case i didn't relogin or nothing similar just moved by notification to Review Queues

Is it possible that you somehow ended up on Meta Stack Overflow, which does not have dark mode?

yeah but after setup again on normal stack dark-mode it doesnt turn off anymore

Happened to me right now. I have more than 500 reputation. I don't know if it's related but I got association bonus for joining another site.

Yes, I reproduced it three times now: 1. Be in dark mode on SO (I also have high contrast enabled) 2. Join any other site (and get association bonus? I can't skip this) 3. refresh/open an SO page. Each time I've done this, it drops me out of dark mode and high contrast, resetting to just the default view.

As u pointed out hight contrast im 99% sure i had it enabled (edited question)
But as i try following your instruction it doesn't seems to happen again.

a fix for this went out a few days back, I think it should have resolved this also, would someone be able to check using the same repro steps again?
